# Ruby memoization on ActiveRecord with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to memoize an `ActiveRecord` resultset but can't get it to work properly when passed a parameter. For example:

```
def my_method(parameter)
  @my_method ||= {}

  return @my_method[parameter] if @my_method[parameter]

  @my_method ||= Table.where(field: parameter).order(:sort_by_field)
end
```

I get an error that `order` isn't available on a `Hash`, or a variation of that error, depending on how I tweak the query, e.g., adding `.includes`, etc. If I simply memoize the resultset, it will always return whatever the first method call returned, regardless of the changing `parameter`. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Apologies if this is a duplicate - I saw multiple questions re: memoization but none that seem to cover `ActiveRecord` parameters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `@my_method[parameter] ||= Table...`. And call `.to_a` on that query, to materialize the resultset. Otherwise you're memoizing only the query selectors.

Comment: As above, your memoization always ends on an empty hash currently. Apart from that, you might want to rethink how you're preparing the data. It would be much wiser to prepare all the `parameter`s you might need beforehand and then query for them once.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think normally these would work. Another issue is that the resultset goes through a decorator, which adds `.group` to the results, and I get `(undefined method 'group' for []:Array Did you mean? group_by)`

Comment: "which adds `.group` to the results" - Well yeah, if you fetch and cache records, you can no longer do that.  You could sort arrays in memory with sort_by, as suggested.

Comment: group with group_by, that is.

Comment: These are all great suggestions, so I've upvoted for each one. I've ended up memoizing a downstream method that only includes the `sum` of the resultset, and it's working fine, as there are too many other methods using the main query and changing one thing breaks too many others. Thanks for all the help, I can see using these in other scenarios.